# Google Maps Building Polygon Coordinates

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Is there a way to retrieve the polygon coordinates of buildings on Google Maps?

I could draw an overlay and grab polygon coordinates manually, then try to determine whether a latitude and longitude are in those coord boundaries. But is there a smarter way of doing this?

The goal is to programmatically understand where a set of lat/lng belong to a building.

Comment: Not at present, you could create an [enhancement request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/), or vote for [this one](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4554) (which seems close, however it is on the Streetview API)